# CKEditor - How to show block other than <p> block (startupOutlineBlocks)

Tags: ckeditor, block

I would like to show block like `<p>` block (when you enable `config.startupOutlineBlocks` to `TRUE`) but for another tag like `<div>` or whatever (`<xxx>`) for example ... Is it possible ? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally this is possible, because it's all HTML and CSS. You can create your own plugin which adds proper stylesheet inside the editor. This stylesheet should contain styles which somehow mark the elements that you want to show (e.g. adding outlines). The only limitation will be that it's hard to display a name of every possible tag, because you would need to have separate styles for every possible tag. But if list of tags is limited this will not be a problem.

See the [showblocks](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/showblocks/plugin.js) plugin for inspiration.

Comment: I just added proprieties in my css :) ! I'm dummy to didn't think about it before.... thx !